# Blazor and Webapi Cors Support

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have spent days trying to figure this out.  All of the examples I've found, don't work or I'm not understanding something.  I have a .netCore webapi currently running on https://localhost:5001, and a stand alone blazor Webassembly on https://localhost:5002.  From blazor I initiate an http request:

```
protected async override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    string reqUrl = $"https://localhost:5001/api/District/";
    var response = await http.GetAsync(reqUrl);
}
```

on the webapi I have the following startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        // For Entity Framework  
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));

        // For Identity  
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Adding Authentication  
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        // Adding Jwt Bearer  
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
                };

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                                    builder =>
                                    {
                                        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5002/");
                                    });
            });

        });
    }


// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error on execution:

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:5001/api/District/' from origin 'https://localhost:5002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Can anyone suggest a change to make this work?  I have gone to the MS Docs, but that's like trying to Quran' in Arabic...

Comment: Try to put `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");` before `app.UseAuthorization();`.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Comment: I made the changes as per your answer and it still errors with the message in my original post.  I can hit it from postman without error

Comment: I am also getting an error and have tried everything

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(
              "_mypolicy", builder => builder
              .AllowAnyOrigin()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
          )
           );
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("_mypolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```